# How do I remove duplicate letters from a LinkedList or String in Java?

Tags: java

Hey guys I have been having trouble removing duplicate letters from a string. I have tried for loops using string methods but I dont seen to be getting anywhere. Does anyone know how to either remove duplicate letters from either a linked list or a string. I have a String sent which holds a a a c d e e k o r t. I also have a LinkedList word = new Linked List(); which has the same letters.

Comment: what did u try?

Comment: Add the characters to a set...unless what you have in mind is to remove _consecutive_ duplicate letters?

Comment: You have to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

By utilizing the properties of a LinkedHashSet, which guarantees uniqueness among its elements *and* preserves order:

```
String string = "foobar";
Set<Character> uniqueChars = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for (char character : string.toCharArray()) {
    uniqueChars.add(character );
}
uniqueChars.forEach(character -> System.out.print(character)); // fobar
```

A more advanced alternative is to make use of Java 8 Stream API, which will accomplish the same:

```
String string = "foobar";
LinkedHashSet<Character> uniqueChars = string.chars()
        .mapToObj(character -> (char) character )
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
uniqueChars.forEach(character -> System.out.print(character)); //fobar
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2-3 ways to achieve the same like below:

1. Try to put value in SET

   `new HashSet<>(listWithDuplicates)`
2. The same can be done using Guava as well:

   `Lists.newArrayList(Sets.newHashSet(listWithDuplicates));`
3. Finally – let’s look at a new solution, using Lambdas in Java 8; we’re going to use the distinct() method from the Stream API which returns a stream consisting of distinct elements based on the result returned by equals() method:

`listWithDuplicates.stream()
     .distinct()
     .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Please let me know if it helps..

for Stream api details and example please follow below URL:

https://kpblogs.com/java/java8/java-stream-api-with-example/